# Inserting and Updating values in MS Access Using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have checked most of the forums on this site but I didn't get my Solution.
My problem is Inserting data from vb.net to MS Access but I am not able to do.
Its not showing any error but also its not inserting values in my table. 
I am using very simple code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Add_LEads

    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Private Sub Add_LEads_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\IndGlobalDB.accdb;Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=admin")
        lblDate.Text = Format(Date.Now, "yyyy/MM/dd")
        conn.Open()
        Dim sql As String
        Dim a As Integer
        sql = "select S_No from Leadss"
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read
            a = dr(0)
        End While
        lblNo.Text = a + 1
        conn.Close()
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
        conn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Leadss(S_No,Contact_Person,Mobile_No,Email_Id,Description,First_Follow_Up,Remarks,L_Date,Alternate_no)VALUES('" & lblNo.Text & "','" & txtName.Text & "','" & txtMobile.Text & "','" & txtEmail.Text & "','" & txtWebDescr.Text & "','" & txtFollowUp.Text & "','" & txtRemarks.Text & "','" & lblDate.Text & "','" & txtAlternate.Text & "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conn.Close()
        MsgBox("Saved!!!", vbOK)
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnExit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
        Welcome.Show()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: you're asking for [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: What result your getting from "cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Leadss(S_No,Contact_Person,Mobile_No,Email_Id,Description,First_Follow_Up,Remarks,L_Date,Alternate_no)VALUES('" & lblNo.Text & "','" & txtName.Text & "','" & txtMobile.Text & "','" & txtEmail.Text & "','" & txtWebDescr.Text & "','" & txtFollowUp.Text & "','" & txtRemarks.Text & "','" & lblDate.Text & "','" & txtAlternate.Text & "')""

Comment: Use a try/catch statement block to see what might be going wrong. Also for security reasons, make use of SqlParameters instead of directly putting the TextBox values in your SQL statement.

Comment: @ Anandkumar , No results.... Its not giving any error bt also not showing output.

Comment: I tried with try catch.. I didnt get any error....  I am new to vb actually... I worked with c# so no idea of using SqlParameters.... @Abbas

Comment: Here's an article about the use of SqlParameter: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8180/Using-SQLParameters-with-VB-NET-C

Comment: Can u pls show me by inserting one value through sqlparameter through my code....? @Abbas I will be more cleared then.

Comment: Are your database fields all of text type? Your INSERT statement try to insert only text strings!

Comment: @Steve Mobile no and ALternate no are Numbers and Date is of date/time.

Comment: If the types are numbers then you should convert the value to a database-integer valuetype, same goes for the datetime.

Comment: Dim num, num1 As Integer
        num = Convert.ToInt32(txtMobile.Text)
        num1 = Convert.ToInt32(txtAlternate.Text)
        Dim dates As Date
        dates = Convert.ToDateTime(lblDate.Text)    Is this the way??? @Abbas

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Although I'd put more validation in your code, like validate whether the input really IS a number. If I enter 'foo' in txtMobile, what you're doing then is this: Convert.ToInt32("foo"), which will throw an exception. Try this instead: Dim num As Integer If IsNumeric(txtMobile.Text) Then num = Convert.ToInt32(txtMobile.Text) End If

Comment: Did you try commit before closing your connection?

Answer (score 1):

You should use parametrized query to avoid Sql Injection Attacks and let the JET engine parse your string parameters for invalid characters.

```
 Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
                                                                   Handles btnSave.Click 
    conn.Open() 
    cmd.Connection = conn 

    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Leadss(S_No,Contact_Person,Mobile_No,Email_Id," & _
                      "Description,First_Follow_Up,Remarks,L_Date,Alternate_no) VALUES " & _
                      "(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"


    cmd.Parameters.Clear()
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", lblNo.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", txtName.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", txtMobile.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", txtEmail.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", txtWebDescr.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", txtFollowUp.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", txtRemarks.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p8", lblDate.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p9", txtAlternate.Text)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 
    conn.Close() 
End Sub
```

Said that, this works only if your field types are of text type and not numeric or datetime or boolean, in that case your should convert the input text in the appropriate type using Convert.ToXXXXX methods.
(The example below assumes that your inputs contains valid numbers and dates)

```
....
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", Convert.ToInt32(txtMobile.Text))
.....
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p8", Convert.ToDateTime(lblDate.Text))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p9", Convert.ToInt32(txtAlternate.Text))
```

Another wrong approach is to keep global variables for reuse like your OleDbConnection, OleDbCommand.
This prevent the runtime to dispose these objects when not used. Instead you should follow this approach

```
 Using conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data " +
                  "Source=|DataDirectory|\IndGlobalDB.accdb;" +
                   "Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=admin")   
    Using cmd = New OleDbCommand()
        conn.Open() 
        cmd.Connection = conn 
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ................"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", lblNo.Text)
        ..........
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Still its not working...... I have applied ur code too... I dont know where I am going wrong..... @Steve

Comment: Have you Copy Local = true associated with the database file? If the database is included in the project it will be recopied everytime you start a debug session.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example for the use of SqlParameter and the try/catch block:

```
Dim connection As SqlConnection = As New SqlConnection("YourDbConnection")
Dim command As SqlCommand = connection.CreateCommand()

Try
    connection.Open()
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Leadss(S_No) VALUES (@S_No)"
    command.Parameters.Add("@S_No", SqlDbType.Text)
    command.Parameters["@FirstName"].Value = lblNo.Text
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch Ex As SqlException
    'Process the exception
Finally
    connection.Close()
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Backticks (`` ` ``) in your `FROM` Statement. It should be `` FROM(`Field1`,`Field2`,...etc) Values('value1', 'value2') ``.

Answer (score 0):

write this coding according to your database name, table name, field names in save button's click event...

```
 Using conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\demo for db in access\demo for db in access\DatabaseforDemo.accdb'")
        Using cmd = New OleDbCommand()
            conn.Open()
            cmd.Connection = conn
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO demo1(Name) VALUES('" & TextBox1.Text & "')"
            'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", lblNo.Text)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("saved..")
            conn.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
```

good luck...
hope so it'll help you...!

Answer (score 0):

In your question you said:

> Its not showing any error but also its not inserting values in my table

Try to use Commit.

> A **COMMIT** statement in SQL ends a transaction within a relational database management system (RDBMS) and ***makes all changes visible to other users***. The general format is to issue a BEGIN WORK statement, one or more SQL statements, and then the COMMIT statement. Alternatively, a ROLLBACK statement can be issued, which undoes all the work performed since BEGIN WORK was issued. A COMMIT statement will also release any existing savepoints that may be in use.
>   In terms of transactions, the opposite of commit is to discard the tentative changes of a transaction, a rollback.

quoted here: [Commit (data management)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commit_(data_management))

```
Try
    'Open Connection...

        'Insert Statement....

        'Notification / Msgbox to confirm successful transaction

    Catch ex As Exception
        'RollBack Transaction...
        'Error Management...

    Finally
        'Commit...
        'Close DB Connection....
    End Try
```

[Microsoft Documentation: OleDbTransaction.Commit Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbtransaction.commit(v=vs.110).aspx)

**but remember**: you should use transactions only if you are inserting/updating multiple SQL statements which then make sense for the rollback.

Here is an Example in [Adding transaction management into a form using MS Access 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25532059/ms-access-2010-adding-transaction-management-into-a-form)